# How to use props and child component in my code for listing the todolist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child, fetch-api, react-props

I have a todolist which displays list items fetched using fetch api from jsonplaceholder page, What I want to do is instead of rendering the lisitng in same component I want to create a child compenent and use one object to be sent as a prop to the child component for displaying. below is the code of the listing page and css file. This is how it looks [todolist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQxNa.png)

app.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?userId=1`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((actualData) => {
        // console.log(actualData)
        setTodos(actualData)
        console.log(todos);
      })
  };
  const updateData = (e) => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    const checked = e.target.checked;

    console.log(id, checked);
    if (checked) {
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          completed: true,

        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => console.log(json));

    }
    else {
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          completed: false,

        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => console.log(json));
    }

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [])
  /*checked={todo.completed}*/
  return (
    <div >
      <div className="main">
        <div className='title'>
          <h1>Todo-List</h1>
        </div>
        <ul key={0}>

          {todos.map((todo, num) =>
            <div className='elements' key={num}>

              <li className="list-group-item ">
                <div className='checkBox'>
                  <input type='checkbox' id={todo.id} onChange={updateData} />
                </div >

                <div className='lists'>


                  < Link to={`./More?id=${todo.id}`}>{todo.title}</Link>

                </div>

              </li>  </div>)
          }


        </ul >


      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

app.css

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.main {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  margin: 10% 30% 0% 30%;
  align-items: center;
}


.card {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

.checkBox {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}


.lists {
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  /* border: 1px solid red;*/
  margin-bottom: 10px;

  text-align: left;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;

}

input[type=checkbox]:before {
  border: 4px solid #C46082;
  border-radius: 5px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -2px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1D1D26;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:before {
  content: "";
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -2px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 8px;
}

.elements {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: #1D1D26;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.item-inner .lists {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.elements:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.inputBox {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #15151C;
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}



a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}




h5 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

I don't know how to props and child elements so I am really confused what to edit it the code.

Comment: Check this example on passing down `todo` props to child component. https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-faraday-6rgdnv

Answer (score 0):

You can create another component `TodoItem` that will accept props like `todo` and `updateData`, something like this:

```
function TodoItem({ todo, updateData }) {
  return (
    <div className='elements'>
      <li className="list-group-item">
        <input type='checkbox' id={todo.id} onChange={updateData} />
        ...
      </li>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then you can use that component when you render the list of items inside `App`:

```
<ul>
  {todos.map((todo, num) => (
    <TodoItem key={num} todo={todo} updateData={updateData} />
  )}
</ul>
```